# Select with a size doesnt have the same behavior than normal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

```html
<select size=5>
  <option>
    Option 1
  </option>
  <option>
    Option 2
  </option>
  <option>
    Option 3
  </option>
  <option>
    Option 4
  </option>
</select>
<div>
   <input value="input1" />
   <input value="input2"/>
   <input value="input3"/>
   <input value="input4"/>
   <input value="input5"/>
</div>

<div style="margin-top: 25px">
   <button>Add an option</button>
   <button>Delete an option</button>
   <button>Save an option</button>
</div>
```

**Context** : i want to simply do a select list but it look like it doesn't have the same behavior with a size than normal mode . 
The widget i want to create is a select box with a list of option, you can add or delete an option, and when you click on a specific option, i do an ajax call to get all the information of the selected option and it fills on the inputs, you can save those input for this option by using the save button
At the load of the window, i get all the option linked to the accout and it automaticaly create the select .

**Problems :** it look very simple to code this, but i have a lot of rules to implement, like if you switch to another option and you dont have save the current option, a comfirm bix appear and ask you if you want to save or not the current option, if you say yes it's good you go the next option and it fills the input with the other, if you say no the select have to stay to the previous option but with this kind of select you cannot select something like i've tried to save the previous option and then put the selected="selected" on it and also try to focus() on it but it doesnt work with this kind of select

**Questions :** do you have some example of this kind of widget or do you have some js library who include this kind of widget ?

**Edit** : https://jsfiddle.net/e883gp9z/1/

Comment: There's no programmatic difference between a plain select and one with `size` set on it. If you're having issues it's going to be a problem with your code. Unfortunately we can't help you with that as you haven't shown your code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e883gp9z/ (confirm dont show up but you can't here just select the lastSel var and i try focus() but it doesn't work too

Comment: You didn't include jQuery in the fiddle, and it's missing a last `)`. When you fix those problems it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/e883gp9z/1/

Comment: Thank a lot for this fix .
As you can see you cant's select the previous option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because the logic you're using to store the last selected option and reset it when needed is flawed. It's much simpler to use the string value rather than the element reference. You can also perform the logic in a single `change` event handler - there's no need for the `setTimeout()` or `click` handler. Try this:

```js
var lastSelected = $('#values').val();

$("#values").change(function() {
  if (confirm("Voulez vous sauvegarder avant de quitter ?")) {
    // do code
  } else {
    $(this).val(lastSelected);
  }
  
  lastSelected = $(this).val();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="values" size=5>
  <option selected="selected">Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
  <option>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer